Configuration of journald for multiple services
I would like some guidance. I currently have Apache 2 redirecting its logs to journald using:
`CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t other_vhosts_access_log" vhost_combined`

I have an initial configuration in journald.conf.d/ for rsyslog, and I would like to add a new configuration for Apache logs with entirely different parameters.
Is this possible? The documentation mentions drop-ins, but not multiple configurations.
Thank you.
I tried creating an apache2.conf file in /etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/ with the following content:
`[Journal]
Storage=persistent
Compress=yes
SystemMaxUse=50m
SystemKeepFree=100m
ReadKMsg=no`

After restarting apache2 and systemd-journald, the log rotation in /var/log/journal/binarydirectory/ does not reflect my configuration.
